# Convert multi-row table into one row based on identifier and column values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, join, case

Here is the Table I am working with (Table1):

| Customer ID | Month | Amount Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 | 10 |
| ABC123 | 2 | 20 |
| ABC123 | 3 | 30 |
| ABC123 | 4 | 40 |
| ABC999 | 1 | 15 |
| ABC999 | 2 | 30 |

This is what I want my new table to look like (Table2):

| Customer ID | AmtPaid_M1 | AmtPaid_M2 | AmtPaid_M3 | AmtPaid_M4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 40 |
| ABC999 | 15 | 30 | 0 | 0 |

I want to just have one row per Customer ID that shows how much they paid each month, instead of having the ID repeated for each month. Is there a simple way to do this using joins or case when statements? Thank you!

Comment: Please mention your the name of your dbms.

Comment: Look for `PIVOT` and `cross-tab`.

Comment: Google `SQL Pivot`

Comment: DBMS? I am using SQL is that what you mean?

Comment: No. *Read* the description of the SQL tag

Comment: SQL is a _language_ specified by ISO/ANSI, and implemented (in different versions) by dozens of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot`

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Table1(Customer_ID varchar(50), Month int, Amount_Paid int);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC123',    1,  10);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC123',    2,  20);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC123',    3,  30);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC123',    4,  40);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC999',    1,  15);
 insert into Table1 values('ABC999',    2,  30);
```

Query:

```
 select Customer_Id, [1] AmtPaid_M1,[2]AmtPaid_M2,[3] AmtPaid_M3, [4] AmtPaid_M4 from Table1
 pivot
 (
 max(Amount_Paid) for Month in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
 )pvt
```

Output:

| Customer_Id | AmtPaid_M1 | AmtPaid_M2 | AmtPaid_M3 | AmtPaid_M4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| ABC999 | 15 | 30 | *null* | *null* |

** Assuming that you are using SQL Server

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a39df9b8f5d7181099b0e72ca342a92a)*

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please let me know if you face any difficulties.